# progress bar in pysmb

Tags: python-3.x, progress-bar, statusbar, pysmb

To transfer a file via the SMB protocol I use the following code:

```
file_obj = open('file.txt', 'rb')
connection = SMBConnection(username = 'Admin',
                        password = 'Pa$$w0rd',
                        my_name = '',
                        remote_name = 'PC',
                        domain = 'WORKGROUP',
                        use_ntlm_v2=True)

connection.connect(ip='192.168.10.10')

connection.storeFile(service_name='Share',
                    path='file.txt',
                    file_obj=file_obj)

connection.close()
```

Everything works well, but there is one problem, I would like to monitor the file transfer process, if a large file is used, then the command line freezes for some time until the file is eaten.

I have a certain design with a progress bar `tqdm` for downloading files from the Internet.

```
chunk_size = 1024
        
total_size = int(r.headers['content-length'])
                
for chunk in tqdm(iterable=r.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size), 
total=total_size / chunk_size, unit=' KB', dynamic_ncols=True):
                            f.write(chunk)
```

But I can’t figure out how to connect this construction with my code.

I understand that the `total_size` variable for a file is not calculated this way and I use `total_size = os.path.getsize('file.txt')`

but still I can’t solve the problem to use this progressbar, the error concerns the `iterable=r.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size)` parameter in `for chunk in tqdm` I don’t know how to make a working option with `r`.

Could you tell me please, how can I make a working status bar. You can offer me any option for tracking the status of sending a `file`, you can use any `status bar`, for example `alive_bar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a class that wraps a given file object with a `read` method that updates a `tqdm` object through its `update` method:

```
import os
from tqdm import tqdm

class TQDMFileReader:
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file
        self.tqdm = tqdm(total=os.stat(file.fileno()).st_size, unit='bytes')

    def read(self, size):
        value = self.file.read(size)
        self.tqdm.update(len(value))
        return value
```

so that you can call `connection.storeFile` with `file_obj` wrapped in a `TQDMFileReader` instance:

```
connection.storeFile(service_name='Share',
                    path='file.txt',
                    file_obj=TQDMFileReader(file_obj))
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing1/OverdueJoyousBooleanalgebra

Comment: Super! Thank you!
After searching on the Internet, I found that you can enable the `show_progress=True` parameter in `storeFile`

Comment: You're welcome. Hmm I did check the documentation of [`storeFile`](https://pysmb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/smb_SMBConnection.html#smb.SMBConnection.SMBConnection.storeFile) and did not find the `show_progress` option you mentioned though.

Comment: I found this information here: https://githubissues.com/miketeo/pysmb/205
I’ve also become interested in the `tqdm_kwargs` parameter, I wonder how it works. Thank you.

Comment: Ah cool, I see it in the actual code too. So it's just that the docs have not been updated.